# PYTHON how to make as many variables as needed

Tags: python

I have a loop that's reading over a text file. Each time the loop finds something different, I want it to make a new variable and assign the value in that line of text to the newly created variable. So if the text file looks like this:

3
3
6
1
3
6

The program would've made 3 variables, one for 1, one for 3, and one for 6. How can I do this>

Comment: You probably _don't_ want to do what you say you want to do, so instead, why don't you tell us what you are actually trying to accomplish, so we can help you better?

Comment: Well I'm trying to get all the different numbers there are and then write them into a .txt file as the output. Pyroscope's answers gives me a set which is good enough because I believe you can write a set into a file. I think I'll stick with his answers, BUT if you have anything to add, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you likely want is this...

```
>>> set("3 3 6 1 3 6".split())
set(['1', '3', '6'])
```

Comment: he said he wanted three variables, this creates one set object

Comment: @Hunter: He doesn't *really* want three variables, he just thinks he does because he doesn't know about containers.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this answer is that he can't get to his values in any predictable way, whereas with his proposed "variables" I guess I figured he would have some name for them. In that sense, an [ordered set](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) or hash-dict would be more featureful.

Comment: "variables" in Python are just names (handles) for objects; and of course you would write `unique_numbers = set(..)` in real code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple approaches:

```
mydict = {}
for x in myfile.read().split():
    mydict[x] = None
print mydict
```

Or:

```
class VarContainer(object):
    pass
v = VarContainer()
for x in myfile.read().split():
    setattr(v, 'var' + x, None)
print v.var3
```

But what you're trying to do is a bit unclear.

Comment: This is why sets were added to Python.

Comment: That's one possible interpretation for the original question.  If the OP is wanting to keep a count of how many times each has appeared or something along those lines, a set won't work.  That's why I asked for clarification.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exec` builtin to create variables.

```
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, May 18 2007, 16:56:43)
[GCC 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [3,3,6,1,3,6]
>>> for e in a:
...     exec 'var%s = %e' % (e,e)
...
...
>>> var3
3.0
>>> var6
6.0
>>> var1
1.0
>>>
```

**EDIT**
This is a bad solution and should never be used. It is, however, important to know that something like this IS possible.

Comment: This is horrible, and while it does just what the user asked for, it isn't what he wants.  He wants a dict.

Comment: I never said it was good, and I don't believe I should be downvoted for answering the question that was asked. Many of the other answers solve the problem in a good way, so the OP can use them as reference. I wanted to show the alternative.

Comment: I understand why you answered it as you did, but really, there's *nothing* good about this approach.  Once he has these variables, how will he access them?  With more "exec" hacks?  It's a house of cards built to avoid using a dict for no good reason.  exec is a power tool, not appropriate as an answer to a beginner question.

Comment: You're recommending a bad way to do something that shouldn't be done. You can create new variables the way @WickedGuy suggested (using setattr) without having to use `exec` if that was really necessary (which it isn't).

Comment: @Hunter if you give an answer and you don't qualify it as bad, it's fair to assume you think it's good.

Comment: +1 for doing what is asked for. I'm all for answers explaining better ways of doing things, but I'd like to always see at least one answer showing how to do what is literally asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in an array:

(Assuming python 2.7)
http://docs.python.org/library/array.html

You can then use `array.index(x)` to search if that value is already in the array, and `array.append(x)` to add it to the array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming text_file is some iterable,

```
def get_unique_numbers(text_file):
   temp = []
   for number in text_file:
      if number not in temp:
         temp.append(number)
   return temp
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you have asked for.

```
import sys 
from string import ascii_letters 

# Task 1, remove duplicate elements. 
def nodup(fn): 
    f = open(fn) 
    data = f.read().split() 

    res = [] 
    res.extend((i for i in data if i not in res)) 
    return res 

# Task 2, create the new variables on the fly 
module = sys.modules[__name__] 
filename = "data" 
for idx, value in enumerate(nodup(filename)): 
    setattr(module, ascii_letters[idx], value) 

print (a, b, c) 
# ('3', '6', '1')
```

Comment: @Naveen Try to reconsider your problem and explain it better. It's almost sure that what you want can be obtained in a better way.